# Wii U has no Video Output

Tags: wii-u, hdmi

I have a Wii U. The AV input apparently stopped working one day, which I changed to an HDMI cable to my Smart TV. This also did not pick up any input whatsoever, and I am unable to change any settings via Gamepad because it needs synced. I tried hooking both AV and HDMI high speed to another TV and got nothing. Now what?